# server failover test issue from apache web server to jboss application

Tags: apache, jboss, load-balancing

I have used the proxypass and reverse proxypass inside the httpd.conf in apache server to repoints requests to particular JVM in JBoss server.

I have 2 JBoss servers...during a failover test..one JBoss server is stopped abruptly...the apache cant identifies that the one JBoss server is stopped and hence cant redirect request to the other server.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<Proxy balancer://BALANCER_NAME>
        BalancerMember https://foo1.bar:443 ping=1 loadfactor=1
        BalancerMember https://foo2.bar:443 status=+H ping=1
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / balancer://BALANCER_NAME/
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://BALANCER_NAME/
```

In this configuration all is sent to foo1 and foo2 is in hot standby (status=+H)

Comment: can you pls explain more what loadfactor=1 and status=+H is used for ?

Comment: my understanding is that from your above config BalancerMember https://foo2.bar:443 status=+H ping=1
the second application server takes just the role of a backup server..in hot mode.....I intented to use both servers...so I assume the ping command itself would help right? and also if I give ping =5...it interprets 5 as 5milli seconds right?

Comment: You are right, in that case ping should suffice. Ping is in second, for millisecond you have to add "ms". For the full list of keys you can use, you can refer to : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass